# function calling an error, not sure why. setTimeout()

Tags: jquery

I am getting an error when i call this function in my js file.

```
    function currentGrassColor(grassArea, color){
         var grassField = $('.'+grassArea+'').find('img');
         setTimeout(function(){grassField.attr('src', 'img/grass'+color+'.png')},1000);
     }

    function currentGrassColor(currentProgram_grassBg, Green);
```

And this is the error i get

> Error on line 4919 col 93 Unexpected token punc «;», expected punc «{»
>   of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/company/js/DataContent.js

Comment: Looks like you are missing a semi colon `setTimeout(function(){grassField.attr('src', 'img/grass'+color+'.png')},1000);` should be `setTimeout(function(){grassField.attr('src', 'img/grass'+color+'.png');},1000);`

Comment: You are missing a semi-colon at the end of your anonymous function. And you don't need `function` when you are trying to call a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you are missing an semicolon, also you should put the color in quotes (unless green is a variable)

```
function currentGrassColor(grassArea, color){
     var grassField = $('.'+grassArea+'').find('img');
     setTimeout(function(){
     grassField.attr('src', 'img/grass'+color+'.png');
     },1000);
 }

currentGrassColor(currentProgram_grassBg, "Green");
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be this:

```
function currentGrassColor(grassArea, color) {
    var grassField = $('.' + grassArea + '').find('img');
    setTimeout(function () {
        grassField.attr('src', 'img/grass' + color + '.png');   // was missing ;
    }, 1000);
}

currentGrassColor(currentProgram_grassBg, Green);               // don't need function here you are calling it, not defining it
```

Pro-Tip: paste you code into [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zxQxX/1/) and hit "JSHint". It highlighted all your errors straight away.